# Consume a third party library through a Destionation in Sap Cloud Platform

Tags: proxy, sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

As we can call an external northwind oData service in our consuming sapUI5 app (relying on SCP destinations and routing in neo-app.json), I was wondering if it is possible to expose a custom library and call it in the same way, avoiding CORS issues once deployed.
I can't find any suitable documentation on how to configure such destination.

My requirement is to reference an external library. I prefer not to embed the minified library in my project nor call it with an hardcoded path.

Any help would be **very** appreciated!

EDIT:
This is the Destination I set up for testing purposes... I require the library in the manifest and set up the routing in neo-app.json but the library is still missing in my consuming project.

[image: Test destination]

Comment: You can deploy the library as a BSP fragment on your backend server and pull it from there, which is what you are describing, but that would be equal to just adding it to your project, since you project is deployed the same way. A more traditional way would be to include it into your project or pull the library from a CDN

Comment: I already managed to deploy and consume libraries in all the "traditional" ways as you describe (BSP fragment, application in SCP, sap.ui.loader.config, embed). I am exploring to have a new option focused on SCP. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it? Why shouldn't it work? Use the host of your library URL as the destination, add the destination to your neo-app.json and it should work.

Comment: @Marc of course I've tried it but I can't figure it out why I can't make it work. Maybe I'm defining the destination wrong in SCP.... I feel somewhat comforted if you think is feasible :-). I'll add my configuration in the post

Comment: @Marc I added the Destination configuration in my original post. I usually don't play around with Destination so I honestly can't say if it is correct. If I check the connection is 200: OK though :-)

Comment: Your URL contains `dispatcher`, so I guess it's not a public URL.  Are you sure that NoAuthentication is correct in this case?

Comment: @Marc No, I'm not :-/ I'll try with different authentications... If I refer the same url with in the Component with    sap.ui.loader.config({
    paths: {
     "my/test/path": "https://mylibrary-xxx.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/library",
    }}); the library is correctly loaded

Comment: @Marc Ok, I tried with AppToAppSSO and now everything works... unless the response received is "Note: Your browser does not support JavaScript or it is turned off. Press the button to proceed.". My browser is fine and if I double click on the link in my Network tab the file library.js is correctly transferred :/

Comment: @Bernard in a Fiori Launchpad context the entry point of my app is the Component.js file and I don't have access at the index.html. This is mostly a proof of concept, we're just exporing different options :-) ...but you gave me a new perspective and a new idea, thanks!

Comment: It worked! SCP takes some time to digest edits :) Thanks to all

Comment: Sure @BoghyonHoffmann. Thanks for the appreciation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to answer to my own question: the proposed architecture is feasible: in the following, my working configuration. 
Please note that my destination configuration points to a custom library deployed in the same SCP.

In the SAP Destination:
[image]

In the neo-app.json of the consuming app:

[image]

Then you can reference the library in your controllers as

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "namespace/mylibrary/library"
], function (Controller, library) {....});
```